# numpy generate data from linear function

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, machine-learning

Say I wanted to generate 100 or so data points from a linear function what's the best way to go about it?

An example linear function `y = 0.4*x + 3 + delta`

where delta is a random value drawn from a uniform distribution between -10 and +10

I want delta to be generated for each data point to give some perturbation to the data.

```
import numpy as np

d = np.random.uniform(-10, 10)
```

This seems to fit the bill for delta although I'm unsure exactly how to generate the rest incorporating this.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I don't know how you wanted to generate x, but this will work:

```
In [7]: x = np.arange(100)

In [8]: delta = np.random.uniform(-10,10, size=(100,))

In [9]: y = .4 * x +3 + delta
```

[image]

Comment: `plt.plot(x,y)`  then `plt.show()`  I think you can pass in the keyword arg `linestyle="."` to just show individual datapoints.  http://matplotlib.org/users/pyplot_tutorial.html

Comment: Yeah sorry I spoke too soon, turned out it was pretty straight forward. I used `plt.plot(y, 'x')` to get the data points.

Comment: just to be clear.  plt.plot(y, 'x') without the first x variable causes np.arange(0,len(y)) to be inferred for x-axis.  If you calculate y using any other range, say -50 to 50, the graph will be incorrect

Comment: Ah thank you, I appreciate the warning. I've confirmed this with the docs.

Answer (score 2):

It all rather depends on what `x` values you want to evaluate your function. Assuming you want to plot from -50 to 50 just use `x = np.arange(-50,50)` but then you need `d = np.random.uniform(-10, 10, x.size)`.

Then just run your function: `y = 0.4*x + 3 + delta`.

On the other hand if you want a linearly spaced `x` you can also use `np.linspace` or for logarithmicly spaced `x`: `np.logspace`.

In the end it could look like:

```
x = np.linspace(0, 100, 1000) # 1000 values between 0 and 100
# x = np.arange(-50, 50) # -50, -49, ... 49, 50
delta = np.random.uniform(-10, 10, x.size)
y = 0.4*x + 3 + delta
```