# Wrong intercept in Spark linear regression

Tags: apache-spark, regression, pyspark, linear-regression

I am starting with Spark Linear Regression. I am trying to fit a line to a linear dataset. It seems that the intercept is not correctly adjusting, or probably I am missing something..

With intercept=False:

```
linear_model = LinearRegressionWithSGD.train(labeledData, iterations=100, step=0.0001, intercept=False)
```

[image: Plot with intercept=False]

This seems normal. But when I use intercept=True:

```
linear_model = LinearRegressionWithSGD.train(labeledData, iterations=100, step=0.0001, intercept=True)
```

[image: Plot with intercept=True]

The model that I get in the last case is exactly:

```
(weights=[0.0353471289751], intercept=1.0005127185289888)
```

I have tried with different datasets, step sizes and iterations, but always the model converges the intercept is about 1

EDIT - This is the code I am using:

```
from pyspark.mllib.regression import LabeledPoint
from pyspark.mllib.regression import LinearRegressionWithSGD
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pyspark import SparkContext
sc = SparkContext("local", "regression")

# Generate data
SIZE = 300
SLOPE = 0.1
BASE = -30
NOISE = 10

x = np.arange(SIZE)
delta = np.random.uniform(-NOISE,NOISE, size=(SIZE,))
y = BASE + SLOPE*x + delta
data = zip(range(len(y)), y) # zip with index
dataRDD = sc.parallelize(data)

# Normalize data
# mean = np.mean(data)
# std = np.std(data)
# dataRDD = dataRDD.map(lambda r: (r[0], (float(r[1])-mean)/std))

labeledData = dataRDD.map(lambda r: LabeledPoint(float(r[1]), [float(r[0])]))

# Create linear model
linear_model = LinearRegressionWithSGD.train(labeledData, iterations=1000, step=0.0002, intercept=True, convergenceTol=0.000001)
print linear_model

true_vs_predicted = labeledData.map(lambda p: (p.label, linear_model.predict(p.features))).collect()

# PLOT
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.grid()

y_real = [x[0] for x in true_vs_predicted] 
y_pred = [x[1] for x in true_vs_predicted] 

plt.plot(range(len(y_real)), y_real, 'o', markersize=5, c='b')
plt.plot(range(len(y_pred)), y_pred, 'o', markersize=5, c='r')

plt.show()
```

Comment: Could you try normalizing the data, increasing the number of iterations, and reducing the tolerance? Besides, what version of `apache spark` are you using?

Comment: I was using version 1.6.0, I have installed the new 1.6.1 and no change. Reducing the tolerance and increasing the number of iterations does not change the result. When I normalize the data, the regression line also starts at 1.

Comment: (and this results in a regression line with negative slope for training data with positive slope)

Comment: May you test this using ML?

Comment: Could you give us the dataset?

Comment: sorry, I'm not sure what you mean with ML. I am generating the dataset like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35730534/numpy-generate-data-from-linear-function/35730618#35730618

Answer (score 1):

This is because the number of iterations and the step size are both smaller. As a result, The trial process is ending before reaching the local optima.